# How to automatically close rewarded video ad in onRewarded method

Tags: android, admob

After the rewarded video ad is displayed the onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) method is called and I want at this moment to close the full screen add automatically in order to display the reward to the user. How I do that?

Comment: test this rewardedVideoAdInstance.destroy(context);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call destroy(context) on the instance of Rewarded Video Ads

```
rewardedVideoAdInstance.destroy(context);
```